# Determine client id of user-assigned managed identity at runtime?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

How do I determine the Client Id of a user-assigned managed identity to an app service or function running on Azure? It's possible to assign multiple user-assigned managed identities and I'd like to get a list of the ones assigned to my app at runtime.

The goal of this is to avoid having to store the client id of the managed user identity in configuration for use in creating a `DefaultAzureCredential` for accessing KeyVault and other resources.

Right now my code looks like the following:

```
string managedIdentityClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ManagedIdentityClientId", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
var options = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = managedIdentityClientId };
var keyVaultCredentials = new DefaultAzureCredential(options);
```

I'd like to avoid storing the `ManagedIdentityClientId` in app settings and simply read it from the configured app service if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get the client id of the user-assigned managed identity at runtime without credentials.

Even if you can use another way e.g. call the REST API in the code to get them, you will also need to use another credential(e.g. service principal), means you also need to expose the client id and secret in the code or store them in the app setting, this makes no sense.

So in your case, I think storing the client id in the app setting is the most feasible way to use MSI.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This seems like a strange limitation since the system-assigned identity doesn't need this. Clearly the underlying library can read these identities. I know these identities can be fetched with Powershell as well.

Comment: @BrianVallelunga 1.Yes, there are differences between them, essentially they are both service principals, you can bind the user-assigned one with different resources, when you use `DefaultAzureCredential()`, it will use the system-assigned one by default. 2.Yes, they can be fetched by powershell, but it also needs the credentials to login with `Connect-AzAccount` first, user or service principal.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can have multiple user-assigned managed identities on your Azure resource, there is no way to directly infer which user-assigned identity should be used and thus you need to specify it.

For system-assigned managed identities, you don't need to specify the clientId because you can only have 1 system-assigned per resource.

> "I'd like to avoid storing the ManagedIdentityClientId in app settings and simply read it from the configured app service if possible."

Even if you could enlist all the user-assigned assigned to a resource, you'd have to have logic to pick the right one from the list. It is just easier to be explicitly specify the clientId via Config.

Comment: In my case I have a couple of dozen apps, functions, etc that use a single managed user identity that is configured with access for common resources such as a service bus and a database. Having system identities would require a huge amount of access settings for a few resources, so using a single common identity made sense.

Comment: You should be able to reference the User Assigned Managed Identity by its name. It seems like the Managed Identity concept is, at least partially, to hide the "messy" details of managing a Service Principal. It's unfortunate that, in the end, you still have to know about the ClientId. I have a situation where I don't have direct access to the Azure subscription where the Identity, and the resources it works with, live. I've been able to create ARM templates to do everything I need, and they all work by name, but I still need to jump through hoops, to find out the ClientId and put it into code.

Comment: The client ID is not a confidential ID. It is useless to anyone unless they can publish new code to your app service (or other resource) that has the managed ID with that client ID assigned.